# Communication client-server-client

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gwt-rpc

I have a question about the Communication between a client and a server.

I would like to create a GWT application that can do the following:

The client A fires an event to the server and the server in his turn fire an event to the client B.
Here the client B has to be able to listen to the event all the time.

I wanted to send some event with few data in real time to a connected client B.
is that possible? and if yes how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Here the client B has to be able to listen to the event all the time.

To let client wait for data, you can use Comet [1] (long lived HTTP requests) or WebSockets [2] if targetted JS runtime does support it.

[1] : http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/

[2] : http://code.google.com/p/gwt-ws/

Comment: thanks a lot, I thinks that is what it could help me. I have one more question, how does the comet work on the server site? does the servlet has to be running all the time on the web server?

Answer (score 1):

[here is one example](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideServerCommunication)of course its possible for the communication between client and server you have to use Rpc(Remote Procedure call). you can send and recieve data as a serialized objects via rpc

Comment: thanks for the reply. The problem qhat I have is the communication between two clients over the server. that means client A fire an event or message that has to be received from the client B over the server in real time. The normal RPC allow me to get a serilized object from the server, but I need to get messages from the server without to send a request.

Answer (score 1):

Just store the result of client's  (A's) request in a Database. and write client side code to request the content from the db, process it in the server and give the result back to the client(in your case, client B)

Comment: thanks for the reply, Client B has to receive changes in a real time maner. That means without a request.