# Send server information to client

Tags: gwt, client-server

Last semester we had to develop the game `Ludo` in `JavaScript` and `HTML/CSS`. That was pretty easy. Now we have to develop a backend with `GWT (Java)` to create a multiplayer game. Sadly, we haven’t got much information on how to develop with GWT and the exercise is quite difficult at the beginning.

At the moment I am trying to create a kind of lobby where different players can join.
My idea was to use some input fields, where the player could enter his name and join the lobby. But I don’t know how to give the other clients the information that a new player has joined.

I created an `asynchronous interfaces` (RPC) where a player could submit his name to the server (Like [this](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideServerCommunication) example). This works ok. But how should I share this information? Our docent said we should use JSON to share information’s, but I don’t know how this should help in this situation.
Is there a way to send information’s to the clients? I read a lot and just find to use additional libraries as gwt-comet.

I have really now clue how I could go on. I’m thankful for every help and information!

Greetz

Comment: comet is definitively what you need, take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206985/communication-client-server-client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options: push and pull.

"Pull" option:

Other players get required information when they join the lobby and/or do something else. You can also schedule to pull this information periodically (like once every 10 minutes).  You can use the same RPC mechanism to get data from server to a client. "Pull" means that a client initiates the request and server responds with the information.

"Push" option:

When a new player joins, the server pushes this new data to all other players. The best solution depends on your game implementation. Comet is a good option, as Jean-Michel mentioned, but it's more complicated and "expensive" from resources point of view. You should use this option if you need real-time status updates for your game.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [**Errai**](http://www.jboss.org/errai) and `ErraiBus` in particular. From Java perspective you are only sending some events via event bus (observer **GoF** pattern) and all the magic with **Ajax Push** is happening behind the scenes.